# Is there any proof that high saturation and contrast makes a picture more appealing in social media?

Tags: photo-editing, contrast, saturation

Atm I'm editing some images (Mainly photos of landscapes and food) for a social media campaign. My supervisor is confident that adding high saturation and contrast will lead to more attention in social media, while I am not convinced yet.

Is there any study or proof that high saturation and contrast in a photo will lead to more attention and make the image "shine out"?

Comment: No only in social media...

Comment: Do an A/B test to find out.

Comment: This was considered a truth even before the digital era. Without Photoshop or other image processing software, it had to be solved on a chemical level and therefore colour negative films for the consumer marked are usually made high constrast and high saturation.

Comment: Color is used to invoke an emotion - so too is the lack of color (post-apocalyptic gun ads anyone?). It's not enough to say that you want "more attention" ... what emotion are you trying to convey and is your image, as a whole and it's color sat and contrast, aiding in that endeavor?

Comment: I pray to the  gods that what is *more appealing to social media*   never dictates what is good photography.

Comment: This seems like something that would fit on skeptics.SE as well.

Comment: Kinda reminds me of the [Loundness War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness_war).

Comment: Yes for food, but not for a lot of things - desaturation has been a domination style in social media for many years now.

Comment: As others note, it's sadly true. Variably comparable metrics in other areas may be of interest. |  Power tool battery voltages. Voltages in "top" products continually 
 increased over time - even when doing so offered no real advantage but had disadvantages. 7.2 9 12 15 18 24 ... Volt. With LiIon 18V and now 36V is not unknown. (In VERY high power applications (eg ebikes) this can make sense. ||Camera "megapixel madness" with small sensor cameras having 5 8 10 12 16 20 ... megapixel sensors at the expense of image quality. ||

Comment: @AlaskaMan So, you're praying for photography to never be intended for wide audience, but for some narrow elite? : D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think your manager is right, and that this phenomenon is much more widespread than just photos for social media, or even photography in general.

Take a look in supermarkets, and take in the flashy bright colours and stark contrasts brands use to attract *your* attention. If they get you to look at their product, chances of you buying it shoot up dramatically. That's how it works for social media; get people to look at your content, and they might just get more engaged with your product.

The same counts for the colourful application icons on your smartphone, and especially the notification marks for these apps that attract your attention and engage you with their their product.

---

**Sources for further reading**

- Morton J. Why color matters. COLORCOM. Available from: http://www.colorcom.com/research/why-color-matters. 2010.
- Labrecque LI, Milne GR. Exciting red and competent blue: the importance of color in marketing. Journal of the Academy of Marketing Science. 2012 Sep 1;40(5):711-27.
- Asadollahi A, Givee M. The role of graphic design in packaging and sales of product in Iran. Contemporary Marketing Review. 2011;1(5):30-4.

Answer (score 12):

Up to a point, yes. As [this answers explains very well](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/108992/15871).

On the other hand, there is a point at which one enters the area of ["too much of a good thing!"](https://www.digitalphotomentor.com/photography/2016/09/processing-sins-over-saturation-750px-09.jpg).

[image: https://www.digitalphotomentor.com/photography/2016/09/processing-sins-over-saturation-750px-09.jpg]

Here's the full article rom which the above image was linked: [7 Deadly Photo Editing Sins That Could Ruin Your Images](https://www.digitalphotomentor.com/7-deadly-processing-sins-ruin-images/).

Comment: While that image is ... horrible ..., it *is* going to make you notice it among a bunch of less garish images.

Comment: it's beautiful - in terms of a certain aesthetic.  If you were trying to blend gothic and cyberpunk together in a game, then it would make for good inspiration.  As an accurate yet aestheticly pleasing photo though? no.

Comment: Ahhh my eyes! HDR is so overused these days (and generally, I'd say "improperly"), that image is driving me crazy! ...but, if your belief is that "any press is good press", I suppose even users talking about how "overdone company XYZ's photos are" means they're talking about your company...

Comment: On the other hand, that particular basilica was going for *"god, the video game!"* when it was built. Sure, it's pushed too hard, but it really is that colour.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's really those colors, but those colors are not that saturated when viewed with the naked eye.

Comment: @tfb There can be a difference between "appealing" (as used in the OP) and "noticeable."

Comment: @BruceWayne There's often a difference between "appealing" (what the OP asked about) and "getting press."

Comment: @Tetsujin [This version](https://www.digitalphotomentor.com/photography/2016/09/processing-sins-over-saturation-750px-08.jpg) is much closer to what the eye sees at Montreal's Notre-Dame Basilica.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't straight answer your question but I'd say your supervisor is correct on this one.

MKBHD did a [blind test comparison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5-bo8a4zU0) between smartphones and the result is exactly this theory. The flashiest and most saturated photos always were considered better, even being of lower quality.

It's the sad reality we live in.